# Convert cURL to WebRequest Equivalent in C#, cURL having result dowload jon file as zip output '-o response.zip'

Tags: c#, json, rest, api, curl

I'm trying to convert cURL to C# web-request equivalent. I'm able to convert cURL to C# without response download from cURL (-o response.zip). But only problem I have is, I have no idea in c# code to translate/convert the cURL code for (-o response.zip) response.zip download file cURL syntax.

Below is my cURL.

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-API-TOKEN: 123456789asdfghj1234qqwerewrty" "https://yourdatacenterid.test.com/API/v3/responseexports/ES_1234sdfasas13wer/file" -o response.zip
```

Below is the code so far I have,

```
 string baseURLWithResponseID = "https://yourdatacenterid.test.com/API/v3/responseexports/ES_1234sdfasas13wer/file";

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(baseURLWithResponseID));
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Accept = "*/*";
    request.Headers.Add("X-API-TOKEN", "123456789asdfghj1234qqwerewrty");
    // Here I'm missing how to convert -o response.zip as C# code ?

    var response = request.GetResponse();

     using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream: response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                var jsonresult = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                Response.Write(jsonresult.ToString()); //I'm able to print the response json as a string but I want it to be downloaded as a zip file

                }
```

I got below as result from the string print which is not in a format.
[image]

Please help me to get the API response as json downloadable file in C# from cURL syntax. Thank you.

**Update 1:**

I have modified code as below.

```
    string baseURLWithResponseID = "https://yourdatacenterid.test.com/API/v3/responseexports/ES_1234sdfasas13wer/file";

string path = "c:\\API_Test\\response.json";
var request2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(baseURLWithResponseID));
 request2.Method = "GET";
request2.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
 request2.ContentType = "application/json"; // Tried with "application/gzip" but output no change
 request2.Accept = "*/*";
 request2.Headers.Add("X-API-TOKEN", "123456789asdfghj1234qqwerewrty");
  request2.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate"); // I added this new line 
   var responseFile = request2.GetResponse();

  using (var src = responseFile.GetResponseStream())
          {
            using (var dst = File.Create(path))
             {
                    src.CopyTo(dst);
               }

           }
```

Here is the output Json file, I'm not sure still in Json file is also getting non readable format. if I try same from post man application I got it as a zip file and if I unzip that I could able to read a clean json file.

[image]

Here is the image from API trial version from third party website. Please check my cURL conversion to c#, Am I missing anything ?

[image]

Comment: That's not JSON, it's the ZIP file itself, read it binarily (not using an StreamReader but an Stream) and write it to disk (or store it wherever you want)

Comment: Gusman, thank you for the reply. Yes. your are right the cURL showing output as response.zip. But I'm new to this could you please help me how can I do it. Any sample code or url reference would be helpful.

Comment: Gimme 5 minutes, I will write an example

Comment: Again Thats NOT json, save it as .zip, it's a ZIP file.

Comment: Gusman, Its true. Now i got zip file downloaded to a specified path. I changed path to c:\\API_Test\\response.zip. Now I have to read from there. Thanks for the catching the type issue.

Answer (score 1):

That's not JSON, it's the zip file's content, so you just need to read the stream binarily and write the data to a file.

.net also offers a very easy way to do this, Stream.CopyTo, just copy the response stream to a file stream and you're done:

```
    string baseURLWithResponseID = "https://yourdatacenterid.test.com/API/v3/responseexports/ES_1234sdfasas13wer/file";

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(baseURLWithResponseID));
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Accept = "*/*";
    request.Headers.Add("X-API-TOKEN", "123456789asdfghj1234qqwerewrty");

    var response = request.GetResponse();

    using (var src = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (var dst = File.Create("Path to wherever you want to store the file"))
        {
                src.CopyTo(dst);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please see my update1. I have included my result screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in `AutomaticDecompression` property of `HttpWebRequest`. Just add the following line after creating request:

```
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```